# asp.net mvc + multiple file upload with title and description

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Good afternoon,

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC. My requirement is to create a small web application using  MVC which can upload multiple files with **description and title**. I have found many articles on the web related to single or multiple file upload but still can not find those who talk like what my requirement are.

[image]

The description and file selection block can have as many as user one. They can upload multiple files with description in single Upload button click.

I do need your expertise to help me. 
Best regards,

Veasna

Comment: How about you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is exactly a MVC problem.

What you need here is to send a form who will send multiple files and who will also send data associated to each file (in this case the description of each file).

Actually, with multipart-form data you can send this type of information, however, previous experience tell me that multiple files uploaded just through a multipart-form usually give a lot of trouble.

If your target users are expected to use somewhat modern browsers I'd recommend to use HTML5's javascript file API, which is extremely useful and powerful.

You can use client code to identify which files your user is selecting, which description values is assigning to each file and build a JSON object with all the data.

Once built the data package you can send it to your server through an AJAX call.
On the controller you can have an action that manages this JSON data package and saves it in the way your business model defines it.

You have an excelent starting article for javascript file API here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, you can go through the below link for your reference:-

[Multiple file upload with titles](http://nkhanengineer.blogspot.in/2015/03/multiple-image-upload-giving-title-and.html)

Also some code related to it.

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in ImagesGrid.Rows)
        {
            var title = row.FindControl("txtTitle") as TextBox;
            var description = row.FindControl("txtDescription") as TextBox;
            var imageFile = row.FindControl("flUpload") as FileUpload;
        }
    }
    protected void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtImages.Text != "")
        {
            pnltwo.Visible= true;
        }
        var imageCount = Convert.ToInt32(txtImages.Text);
        var list = new List<string>(imageCount);
        list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(String.Empty, imageCount));
        ImagesGrid.DataSource = list;
        ImagesGrid.DataBind();

    }
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlone" runat="server">

                         <asp:Label ID="lbltext" runat="server" Text="Enter the no of images to upload"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtImages" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqtxt" runat="server" CssClass="error-class" ControlToValidate="txtImages" ErrorMessage="Please enter value"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEnter" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-prm" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnEnter_Click" Width="75px" Text="Upload" />
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <asp:Panel ID="pnltwo" runat="server">

                            <asp:GridView ID="ImagesGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No">
                                        <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DisplayIndex + 1 %></ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="flUpload" runat="server" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" Text="Save" CssClass="btn btn-prm" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" />
                        </asp:Panel>
```